# Induction proof of strict inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Prove that if $2 \lt x \lt 3$ and $\space$ $x_{n+1} = 2 + \sqrt{x_n - 2}$ then $o \lt x_n \lt x_{n+1}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

It is apparent to me that we assume that $2 \lt x_n \lt 3$ Then we use a base case $n = 1$ We get $2 \lt x_1 \lt 3$

To show that this holds true for $n + 1$:

$$0 \lt x_n - 2 \lt 1$$

$$0 \lt \sqrt{x_n-2} \lt 1$$

$$2 \lt 2 + \sqrt{x_n - 2} \lt 3$$

$$2 \lt x_{n+1} \lt 3$$

So our assumption holds true. This also shows that both are obviously greater than 0. The problem that I have is showing that $$x_n \lt x_{n+1}$$

What I did in a similar exercise was I plugged in $2 + \sqrt{x_n - 2}$ for $x_{n+1}$ and set that greater than $x_n$ and moved the two over so that I got:

$$x_{n}-2 \lt \sqrt{x_n - 2}$$ and set $x = x_n - 2$

in order to get $x \lt \sqrt{x}$

Appearently this was wrong though and I am not sure how I am supposed to show that $x_n \lt x_{n+1}$  if my work is wrong can someone explain why it is false?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:x\mapsto 2+\sqrt{x-2}-x$ such that $x_{n+1}-x_n=f(x_n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. You can easily show that $f'(x)=\frac{1-2\sqrt{x-2}}{2\sqrt{x-2}}<0$ for all $x\in]2,3[$, hence $f$ is stricly decreasing on $]2,3[$ and $\forall x\in]2,3[,\,f(x)>f(3)=0$. Because $x_n\in ]2,3[$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x_{n+1}-x_n=f(x_n)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Computing $$x_{n+1}-x_n=2-x_n+\sqrt{x_n-2}$$ Now we get
$$\sqrt{x_n-2}>x_n-2$$ if $$0>x_n^2-5x_n+6$$ and this is equivalent to
$$0>(x_n-2)(x_n-3)$$ which is true.

Comment: I feel like there are steps missing

Comment: Why would I compute the difference of the terms?